# Filter column values (different) one by one using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I am trying to filter values of a column one by one. Values subjected to filter comes different every time. Is there a  way that a macro can capture this out.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Open").Select
    'invoice value less than 0
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    'Selected Country
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ARG"
    'Selected invoice#
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="1007225"
    Range("G528").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="1015678"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="1018523"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$2700").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="1018962"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have and explain further the _exact_ issue you are having?

Comment: Both the nested arrays and the dictionary object are standalone. The only `With ... End With` block references the worksheet as a whole. The `For ... Next` loops can be assigned independent vars to be used as counters.

Comment: I have found a way to copy all values of field 3 to a  different sheet and remove duplicates there. I then have 8-9 values. But how and where can I input these in current program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuff your `.AutoFilter` fields into a nested variant array and look through the sets using the *rank* with `LBound` and `UBound`.

```
Sub a1Multi_Filter()
    Dim v As Long, vCRITs As Variant
    Dim vKey As Variant, dCOL7s As New Scripting.Dictionary

    dCOL7s.CompareMode = BinaryCompare

    vCRITs = Array(Array(11, "<0"), _
                   Array(3, "ARG"), _
                   Array(7, "1007225"), _
                   Array(7, "1015678"), _
                   Array(7, "1018523"), _
                   Array(7, "1018962"))

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        For v = LBound(vCRITs, 1) To UBound(vCRITs, 1)
            .AutoFilter Field:=vCRITs(v)(0), Criteria1:=vCRITs(v)(1)

            'pause for effect and processing
             MsgBox "array presets" & Chr(10) & "filtered " & .Address(0, 0) & " on column " & Chr(64 + vCRITs(v)(0)) & " for " & vCRITs(v)(1)

            .AutoFilter Field:=vCRITs(v)(0)
        Next v
        .AutoFilter

        For v = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(v, 7).Value)) And Not dCOL7s.Exists(.Cells(v, 7).Value) Then _
                dCOL7s.Add Key:=.Cells(v, 7).Value, Item:=7
        Next v

        For Each vKey In dCOL7s.Keys  'v = 0 To (dCOL7s.Count - 1)
            .AutoFilter Field:=dCOL7s.Item(vKey), Criteria1:=vKey

            'pause for effect and processing
            MsgBox "column 7 special" & Chr(10) & "filtered " & .Address(0, 0) & " on column " & Chr(64 + dCOL7s.Item(vKey)) & " for " & vKey

            .AutoFilter Field:=dCOL7s.Item(vKey)
        Next vKey
    End With
    dCOL7s.RemoveAll: Set dCOL7s = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've left you plenty of room for processing and the message text should help to explain the elements of the variant array(s).

After setting up the pairs of field indexes and criteria arguments, the `For ... Next` loop uses the first rank's lower and upper boundaries for the limits of processing. Each set is applied in turn and I've paused with a msgbox showing the autofilter range, filtered field and filter criteria. After 'processing' the autofilter for that field is cleared in preparation for the next in the sequence.

**Addendum:**

I've added the collection of unique items from column G into a scripting dictionary and then cycled through the dictionary keys and items, using each pair as filter and criteria in the same `.AutoFilter`. To use a scripting dictionary, you need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* to the project. This only needs to be added once; not for every computer that this may run on but if a new project is started that uses a scripting dictionary, it will have to be added to that project as well.

Comment: Awesome..! Works Great. But how about if Criteria value in field 7 changes from time to time or if we have to filter through all the values one by one. Thanks..!!

Comment: @McGill - A scripting dictionary object would be the best method of collecting a unique set of the values from column 7. The nested variant array works best fro preset criteria.

Comment: What I am trying to do now is: Will copy the unique values through a macro on to a different sheet and then will assign a range to a vaiable. that variable will then get a call from Array(7,"") in the vCRITs criteria. code is below:

Comment: Sub Multi_Filter()
    Dim v As Long, vCRITs As Variant
    Dim po As Range
    Set po = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
    vCRITs = Array(Array(11, "<0"), _
                   Array(3, "ARG"), _
                   Array(7, po))
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        For v = LBound(vCRITs, 1) To UBound(vCRITs, 1)
            .AutoFilter Field:=vCRITs(v)(0), Criteria1:=vCRITs(v)(1)
            'pause for effect and processing
            MsgBox "filtered " & .Address(0, 0) & " on column " & Chr(64 + vCRITs(v)(0)) & " for " & vCRITs(v)(1)

Comment: .AutoFilter Field:=vCRITs(v)(0)
        Next v
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub

Comment: @McGill - a) please see the revisions I've added for a scripting dictionary. b) putting code into a comment is never a good thing. Edit your original question or if there is sufficient new material, consider this thread closed and start a new question with your updated code and sample data.

Comment: @ Jeeped - in response to: Addendum:

I've added the collection of unique items from column G into a scripting dictionary and then cycled through the dictionary keys and items, using each pair as filter and criteria in the same .AutoFilter. To use a scripting dictionary, you need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add Microsoft Scripting Runtime to the project. This only needs to be added once; not for every computer that this may run on but if a new project is started that uses a scripting dictionary, it will have to be added to that project as well.

Comment: @ Jeeped - in response to:  'Addendum:' note, This Macro still gives an issue. it doesn't filter field 3 and 11 w.r.t. field 7 values. filteration continues only up to listed 4 values of Macro but what about the rest of other values? when thety start falling, filteration criteria stops working there and only values of field 7 start showings up. For a real test, if you update various values in 3,7,11 field situation will be clear.Thanks.