# Extract a word from string with noise and print it in the next column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns (column A and B) of data with lots of noise that I am trying to extract certain words out of and print those words in the next columns using VBA. The columns go as follows (comma separates the rows):

```
Column A: Blah, Blah, Y, Blah
Column B: Blah, %_Y, Blah
```

Code so far (from comments):

```
Sub try() 
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "BHA"
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 
        .AutoFilterMode = False 
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
        With .Range("A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With 
End Sub
```

I would like to extract the word "Y" from both columns when "Y" is found in a row, I would like to have it printed in the exact same row in Column C.

Comment: please share your code you have tried before

Comment: What do you want if it is in one of the cells? What if it is in both of the cells? What if it is in none of the cells? If you had included what you had tried (working or not) then these questions would have been answered.

Comment: Sub try()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "BHA"

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Comment: ... so .... now you want to delete the row ...?

Comment: Azure - I get that you need some help getting started but when you ask for putting a value in column C and supply code that deletes a row some clarification is in order. Either you have misinterpreted what you were trying or simply don't know what a delete command does; I cannot tell from this side of the computer screen. That code would have been better if you had removed the delete command and simply put a comment in that said `'here is where I want to put a value in C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. It will search COL A for the key word, then search COL B for the key word. If the word is found in either A or B, it will print the word in COL C of the same row.

**This is with Single Search Term**

```
Sub ExtractKeyWordFromColAAndColB()

    Dim SearchedWord As String
    Dim NewString As String
    Dim LengthWord As Long
    Dim IndexStartWord As Long
    SearchedWord = "Y" 'The Key Word
    LengthWord = Len(SearchedWord) 'The Length of the key word

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        NewString = "" 'Set to EMPTY with each iteration

        If InStr(UCase(Range("A" & i).Value), UCase(SearchedWord)) > 0 Then 'Look for Key word in Column A; Not Case sensitive
            IndexStartWord = WorksheetFunction.Find(UCase(SearchedWord), UCase(Range("A" & i).Value))
            NewString = Mid(Range("A" & i).Value, IndexStartWord, LengthWord)
        End If

         If InStr(UCase(Range("B" & i).Value), UCase(SearchedWord)) > 0 Then 'Look for Key word in Column B; Not Case sensitive
            IndexStartWord = WorksheetFunction.Find(UCase(SearchedWord), UCase(Range("B" & i).Value))
            NewString = NewString + " " + Mid(Range("B" & i).Value, IndexStartWord, LengthWord)
        End If

        Range("C" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(NewString)


    Next i

End Sub
```

**This is with Multiple Search Terms**

```
Sub ExtractKeyWordFromColAAndColB()

    Dim NewString As String
    Dim ColumnLetter As String
    Dim IndexStartWord As Long
    Dim SearchedWord(0 To 2) As String 'Key Words; You may add more to the list.
    'If you add more to the list update numbers above (i.e. SearchedWord(0 To 2))
    SearchedWord(0) = "X"
    SearchedWord(1) = "Y"
    SearchedWord(2) = "Z"

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        NewString = "" 'Set to EMPTY with each iteration

        For k = 1 To 2

            If k = 1 Then ColumnLetter = "A" Else ColumnLetter = "B"

            For j = 0 To UBound(SearchedWord) 'Look for Key words; Not Case sensitive
                If InStr(UCase(Range(ColumnLetter & i).Value), UCase(SearchedWord(j))) > 0 Then
                    IndexStartWord = WorksheetFunction.Find(UCase(SearchedWord(j)), UCase(Range(ColumnLetter & i).Value))
                    NewString = NewString + "-" + Mid(Range(ColumnLetter & i).Value, IndexStartWord, Len(SearchedWord(j)))
                End If
            Next j
        Next k

        Range("C" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(NewString, "-", "", 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Azure Yes, that is possible. I am tied up right now, but I am happy to tweak the code to do what you're asking. I'll respond shortly. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Azure I updated my original post. It should work OK for you. The only thing is if "X" appears in COL A and "X" appears in COL B too, then you will get A-A. Not sure if having duplicates matters. If you are happy with the answer, would you mind selecting the check mark next to my post. I'm a newbie too and trying to build my rep here (for bragging points and hopefully a programming job somewhere soon!). Thank you!!

Comment: @Azure Same to you!! Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

This short snippet is taken largely from the snippet you provided but replaces the row deletion with stuffing the value of the strSearch var in column C on the matching rows.

```
Sub try_again()
    Dim strSearch As String, c As Long

    strSearch = "BHA"
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        For c = 1 To 2
            With Intersect(.Columns(c), .UsedRange)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Chr(42) & strSearch & Chr(42)
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .Offset(0, 2 + (c > 1)) = strSearch
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        Next c
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The native worksheet [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) is used to check for visible rows since its [COUNTA sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) does not count hidden values.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Suggest you close off this question (click the checkmark on the left beside one of the suggested answers) then start work on modifying the code. [Hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084078/filter-column-values-different-one-by-one-using-excel-vba/29107536#29107536). If you run into trouble, start a new question with your own effort, noting where you are having trouble and any error messages that you are receiving.